# Training/Predicting with CNN / ResNet on all classes each iteration - concatenation of input data + Hungarian algorithm

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist, resnet

So I've got a simple pytorch example of how to train a ResNet CNN to learn MNIST labeling from this link:

https://zablo.net/blog/post/using-resnet-for-mnist-in-pytorch-tutorial/index.html

It's working great, but I want to hack it a bit so that it does 2 things. First, instead of predicting digits, it predicts animal shapes/colors for a project I'm working on. That's already working quite well already and am happy with it.

Second, I'd like to hack the training (and possibly layers) so that predictions is done in parallel on multiple images at a time. In the MNIST example, basically prediction (or output) would be done for an image that has 10 digits at a time concatenated by me. For clarity, each 10-image input will have the digits 0-9 appearing only once each. The key here is that each of the 10 digit gets a unique class/label from the CNN/ResNet and each class gets assigned exactly once. And that digits that have high confidence will prevent other digits with lower confidence from using that label (a Hungarian algorithm type of approach).

So in my use case I want to train on concatenated images (not single images) as in Fig A below and force the classifier to learn to predict the best unique label for each of the concatenated images and do this all at once. Such an approach should outperform single image classification - and it's particularly useful for my animal classification because otherwise the CNN can sometimes return the same ID for multiple animals which is impossible in my application.

I can already predict in series as in Fig B below. And indeed looking at the confidence of each prediction I am able to implement a Hungarian-algorithm like approach post-prediction to assign the best (most confident) unique IDs in each batch of 4 animals. But this doesn't always work and I'm wondering if ResNet can try and learn the greedy Hungarian assignment as well.

[image]

In particular, it's not clear that implementing A simply requires augmenting the data input and labels in the training set will do it automatically - because I don't know how to penalize or dissalow returning the same label twice for each group of images.  So for now I can generate these training datasets like this:

```
print (train_loader.dataset.data.shape)
print (train_loader.dataset.targets.shape)
torch.Size([60000, 28, 28])
torch.Size([60000])
```

And I guess I would want the targets to be [60000, 10]. And each input image would be [1, 28, 28, 10]?  But I'm not sure what the correct approach would be.

Any advice or available links?

I think this is a specific type of training, but I forgot the name.